# Print pi to a number of decimal places

Tags: python, pi

One of the challenges on w3resources is to print pi to 'n' decimal places. Here is my code:

```
from math import pi

fraser = str(pi)

length_of_pi = []

number_of_places = raw_input("Enter the number of decimal places you want to 
see: ")

for number_of_places in fraser:
    length_of_pi.append(str(number_of_places))

print "".join(length_of_pi)
```

For whatever reason, it automatically prints pi without taking into account of any inputs. Any help would be great :)

Comment: Is the challenge to print `pi` *rounded* to n decimal digits, or print the *first n decimal digits* of `pi`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not just `format` using `number_of_places`:

```
''.format(pi)
>>> format(pi, '.4f')
'3.1416'
>>> format(pi, '.14f')
'3.14159265358979'
```

And more generally:

```
>>> number_of_places = 6
>>> '{:.{}f}'.format(pi, number_of_places)
'3.141593'
```

In your original approach, I guess you're trying to pick a number of digits using `number_of_places` as the control variable of the loop, which is quite hacky but does not work in your case because the initial `number_of_digits` entered by the user is never used. It is instead being replaced by the iteratee values from the `pi` string.

Comment: I think that kinda defeats the whole challenge? Would there be a way to modify the number of decimal places in correspondence to a given input?

Comment: @Fraser There is the *more generally* part in the answer :)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thanks for the answer, that answered my question as well. I am a total newbie. I tried to directly put the input content as (pi, ' .inputf) and of course it didn't work. The '{ }' you used in the general part in the answer is a game changer. Where can I learn more about that? Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

The proposed solutions using `np.pi`, `math.pi`, etc only only work to double precision (~14 digits), to get higher precision you need to use multi-precision, for example the mpmath package

```
>>> from mpmath import mp
>>> mp.dps = 20    # set number of digits
>>> print(mp.pi)
3.1415926535897932385
```

Using `np.pi` gives the wrong result

```
>>> format(np.pi, '.20f')
3.14159265358979311600
```

Compare to the true value:

```
3.14159265358979323846264338327...
```

Answer (score 2):

For example the `mpmath` package

```
from mpmath import mp
def a(n):
   mp.dps=n+1
   return(mp.pi)
```

Answer (score 2):

Great answers! there are so many ways to achieve this. Check out this method I used below, it works any number of decimal places till infinity:

```
#import multp-precision module
from mpmath import mp
#define PI function
def pi_func():
    while True:
        #request input from user
        try:
             entry = input("Please enter an number of decimal places to which the value of PI should be calculated\nEnter 'quit' to cancel: ")
             #condition for quit
             if entry == 'quit':
                 break
             #modify input for computation
             mp.dps = int(entry) +1
         #condition for input error
         except:
                print("Looks like you did not enter an integer!")
                continue
         #execute and print result
         else:
              print(mp.pi)
              continue
```

Good luck Pal!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution appears to be looping over the wrong thing:

```
for number_of_places in fraser:
```

For 9 places, this turns out be something like:

```
for "9" in "3.141592653589793":
```

Which loops three times, one for each "9" found in the string.  We can fix your code:

```
from math import pi

fraser = str(pi)

length_of_pi = []

number_of_places = int(raw_input("Enter the number of decimal places you want: "))

for places in range(number_of_places + 1):  # +1 for decimal point
    length_of_pi.append(str(fraser[places]))

print "".join(length_of_pi)
```

But this still limits `n` to be less than the `len(str(math.pi))`, less than 15 in Python 2.  Given a serious `n`, it breaks:

```
> python test.py
Enter the number of decimal places you want to see: 100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    length_of_pi.append(str(fraser[places]))
IndexError: string index out of range
>
```

To do better, we have to calculate PI ourselves -- using a series evaluation is one approach:

```
# Rewrite of Henrik Johansson's (Henrik.Johansson@Nexus.Comm.SE)
# pi.c example from his bignum package for Python 3
#
# Terms based on Gauss' refinement of Machin's formula:
#
# arctan(x) = x - (x^3)/3 + (x^5)/5 - (x^7)/7 + ...

from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

TERMS = [(12, 18), (8, 57), (-5, 239)]  # ala Gauss

def arctan(talj, kvot):

    """Compute arctangent using a series approximation"""

    summation = 0

    talj *= product

    qfactor = 1

    while talj:
        talj //= kvot
        summation += (talj // qfactor)
        qfactor += 2

    return summation

number_of_places = int(input("Enter the number of decimal places you want: "))
getcontext().prec = number_of_places
product = 10 ** number_of_places

result = 0

for multiplier, denominator in TERMS:
    denominator = Decimal(denominator)
    result += arctan(- denominator * multiplier, - (denominator ** 2))

result *= 4  # pi == atan(1) * 4
string = str(result)

# 3.14159265358979E+15 => 3.14159265358979
print(string[0:string.index("E")])
```

Now we can take on a large value of `n`:

```
> python3 test2.py
Enter the number of decimal places you want: 100
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067
>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, really elementary but works (max 15 decimal places):

```
pi = 22/7
while True:

    n = int(input('Please enter how many decimals you want to print: '))

    if n<=15:
        print('The output with {} decimal places is: '.format(n))
        x = str(pi)
        print(x[0:n+2])
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter a number between 0 and 15')
```

Comment: The question is to print any N decimal of pi, not the first 15. But something in that spirit should work.

Comment: Yes! the same code would work for more than 15 numbers after the decimal point if we have a higher precision on the value of Pi. The math library displays just 15 numbers after the decimal which is why I put that condition. Please let me know if you're aware of how we can obtain Pi with a higher precision, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As this question already has useful answers, I would just like to share how i created a program for the same purpose, which is very similar to the one in the question.

```
from math import pi
i = int(input("Enter the number of decimal places: "))
h = 0
b = list()
for x in str(pi):
    h += 1
    b.append(x)
    if h == i+2:
        break

h = ''.join(b)
print(h)
```

Thanks for Reading.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
import numpy as np

def pidecimal(round):
    print(np.round(np.pi, round))
```

Answer (score 0):

For 6 decimal digits you can use

```
print (f"{math.pi:.6f}")
```