# finding PI value using "Python"

Tags: python, math, pi

I am trying to get `pi` value in python. Here is my source code.

```
import math
pi_formatted_float = "{:.5000f}".format(math.pi)
print(pi_formatted_float)
```

Using the source code I only can get 48 decimal places. Others are only 00000000....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print pi to a number of decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416626/print-pi-to-a-number-of-decimal-places)

Comment: Specifically, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57442623/14722562) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45416807/14722562) which use the `mpmath` library.

Answer (score 1):

More simply, you can test with

```
>>> "{:.60f}".format(1/3)
'0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125000000'
```

It's not just a problem of PI, but common in all `float` type. You may find more information from [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455612/14257620).