# How to calculate PI with Python

Tags: python, computer-science

We have to calculate Pi.

My code

```
import sys

import math

for s in sys.stdin:
    m = math.pi
    t = str(m).split(".")
    tok = ("").join(t)
    x = tok[0] + "."
    r = t[1]
    y = int(s)
    print(x + r[0:y])
```

This calculates PI but my professor wants it to be

1 = 3.1

2 = 3.14

3 = 3.142

4 = 3.1416

5 = 3.1415926536

Mine is
3.1

3.14

3.141

3.1415

3.1415926535

How do I make it similar to my professors?

Comment: Or [Print pi to a number of decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416626/print-pi-to-a-number-of-decimal-places)

Comment: Change your print to `print(f'{y} = {x + r[0:y]}')`

Comment: Converting the inbuilt `math.pi` to a string and truncating its length hardly counts as _"calculating"_ the value of pi.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that

`array[count]=len(str(pi).split(".")[1])`

Then it is easy to print the way you want