# i need more decimal places for pi calculation

Tags: python, decimal, floating-accuracy, pi

I'm trying to make a Pi calculator in python but I need more decimal places.

it would help a lot if someone edited my code and carefully explained what they did.

this is the code I'm using.

```
import math
d = 0
ans = 0
display = 0
while True:
    display += 1
    d += 1
    ans += 1/d**2
    if display == 1000000:
        print(math.sqrt(ans*6))
        display = 0
    # displays value calculated every 1m iterations
```

output after ~85m iterations: (3.14159264498239)

I need more than 15 decimal places (3.14159264498239........)

Comment: More compared to what? What is your actual requirement? Also, instead of `while loop == loop`, you would typically use `while True` for an infinite loop.

Comment: i need more decimal places in the output because im calculating a value with seemingly an infinite number of them.

Comment: You can't expect Stack Overflow users to download and run your code (in the general case). You should clearly indicate what your actual and desired results are.

Comment: Take a look at the `decimal` package

Comment: Find a better approximation series. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Efficient_methods

Comment: @Calculuswhiz how does that help with the problem of lack of float precision?

Comment: @JonSG That's only part of the problem. Even with python's normal float precision, the series is extremely inefficient. At 12 million iterations, the series is only accurate to 6 digits, which python can represent without issue.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz While the approach is not optimal, the problem they have is clearly stated as "*I need more decimal places*"

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416626/print-pi-to-a-number-of-decimal-places

Answer (score 1):

You’re using a very slowly converging series for π²∕6, so you are not going to get a very precise value this way. Floating point limitations prevent further progress after `3.14159264498239`, but you’re not going to get much further in any reasonable amount of time, anyway. You can get around these issues by some combination of

- micro-optimising your code,
- storing a list of values, reversing it and using `math.fsum`,
- using `decimal.Decimal`,
- using a better series (like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80)),
- using a method that converges to the value of π quickly, instead of a series (like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm)),
- using PyPy, or a faster language than Python,
- `from math import pi`.

Comment: i'm a year late but thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could try with a generator:

```
def oddnumbers():
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 2


def pi_series():
    odds = oddnumbers()
    approximation = 0
    while True:
        approximation += (4 / next(odds))
        yield approximation
        approximation -= (4 / next(odds))
        yield approximation


approx_pi = pi_series()

for x in range(10000000):
    print(next(approx_pi))
```

Comment: i know this is like a year late but thanks!